# Form data not updating after calling action with ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table in my form and I don't want it to display until a link on the page is clicked which would call an action to get the data and redirect back to the same view so the table is populated.  In essence like a master/detail form.  I added a css class to hide the table but the only way I know of to call the action is to use ajax.  I wrote the code for the function but and it seems to work fine but the table does not populate and I can't figure out why. I am using a partial view for the table which is supposed to be populated after the link is clicked.  I'm very new to MVC so I have no idea what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

This is the link used in the jquery click event

```
<td><a id="viewOrder" href="#" data-PONumber-id=@osOrder.PurchaseOrderNumber>View Order</a></td>
```

This is my jQuery to call the action in the controller

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#viewOrder").on("click",
            function(e) {

                var button = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Receiving")',
                    data: { "id": button.attr("data-PONumber-id") },
                    success: function() {
                            var orderButton = $(".js-Order");
                            orderButton.removeClass("invisible");
                            orderButton.addClass("visible");
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

This is my controller code.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var purchaseOrder = _context.PurchaseOrders.Single(p => p.PurchaseOrderNumber == id);

        var viewModel = new ReceivngFormViewModel
        {
            PO = purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderNumber,
            Vendor = purchaseOrder.Vendor.VendorName,
            Contact = purchaseOrder.Vendor.Phone,
            OutstandingOrders = _context.PurchaseOrders.Where(od =>
                od.Closed == false && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(od.PurchaseOrderNumber.ToString()) &&
                od.OrderDate != null).ToList(),
            ReceivedOrderDetails = _context.PurchaseOrderDetails
            .Where(pod => pod.PurchaseOrderID == purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderID && (pod.Quantity - pod.ReceiveOrderDetails
            .Sum(rod => rod.QuantityReceived)) != 0)
            .Select(pod => new ReceivedOrderDetail
            {
                PurchaseOrderId = pod.PurchaseOrderID,
                PurchaseOrderDetailId = pod.PurchaseOrderDetailID,
                PartId = pod.PartID,
                PartDescription = pod.Part.Description,
                QtyOnOrder = pod.Quantity,
                QtyOutstanding = pod.ReceiveOrderDetails.Select(rod => rod.QuantityReceived).Any() ?
                    pod.Quantity - pod.ReceiveOrderDetails.Sum(rod => rod.QuantityReceived) : pod.Quantity
            }).ToList()
        };
        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: You making an ajax call and returning html (which should be a partial view) but you never do anything with it. You need to add it to the DOM in the success callback - `success: function(data) { $(someElement).html(data) ... }`

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, only thing is in the master part of the form, if there is more than 1 record and I click on the view order link from the first one it works fine but it won't work on any of the others, why would that be?  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You have not given enough detail to understand what you mean, but I assume you are replacing the whole table (you should only be replacing what you need), but if you are then you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). It also look like you have multiple elements with `id="viewOrder"` which is invalid html

Comment: Got it going, it was the viewOrder, didn't realize I set it as the id rather than a class.  Probably would have taken me a while to realize that, thanks for pointing it out and thanks for the other part as well, worked great.